# gui-based scripting that interacts with ajax/http captures for web crawling/scraping

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, web-crawler, fiddler

I'm testing a web application that is primarily ajax based served up with jsp. Everything is dynamically created/allocated on the application's end. I'm trying to create some kind of crawler/scraper that must do the following:

1. "click" every available button, drop-down, etc on a given webpage
2. for every request, record what the client/server interactions are
3. once a single web page has had all of its buttons pressed (ha?), 
     breadth-first search starting with the first record from #2
4. continue until all records have been interacted with once.

I'm easily able to use python to click, though python is not a neccessity (I know Java has some things that might work easily enough):

```
def click(x,y):
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

I've looked up recording software such as fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

I cannot figure out how to record the interaction, but not change screens. e.g. on page A, button B moves to page C, I want to click B, but stay on A (this is an oversimplified case)

I thoroughly understand breadth-first searching, though I don't know how to load a webpage using whatever scripting/programming language there is (from #1).

So, does anybody know how to record the interaction (perhaps keeping it in a queue for easy BFS)? And, does anybody know how to load a request from some recording software?

As a side-note, the time it takes to do all of this is not important, if it takes months, even that is okay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use a tool like autoit (which does have python bindings...)  or one I like even better called SIKULI (http://sikuli.org/)  (which does not have python bindings... but its own scripting language which is cool)

Answer (score 0):

selenium has python bindings (http://seleniumhq.org/); you could use that.

is there any reason why this needs to be GUI based ?  you'd have a much easier time outside of a GUI.

you're going to need to keep a datastore of the possible links on every page, and where they go to.  with a gui based control, you could conceivably open links in new browser windows, but that would likely spiral out of control.

Comment: this will eventually be a part of a security suite test, and we're focusing on visible buttons. also, the ways I'd normally write a crawler (looking for href let's say) are incompatible as most "buttons" are not hyperlinked, but created on the fly based on other information on the web page. Since it's served in jsp, the buttons redirect to pages that aren't a different web address, but has different content. It's frankly a real pain.

Comment: ugh.  well, selenium is probably your best bet.  it's a completely open source web automation tool that runs on most browsers/os, and there are good python bindings.